# Garch model detection

Tags: time-series, garch

Does the plotted data look like a garch model?
If it does, with which test, I can support this claim

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEHr3.png]

```
[1]   0.187415738   0.477868164   0.295777631   0.575167970   0.469157108
  [6]   0.328171826   1.292894322  -0.847711535   0.392077876   0.116540719
 [11]   0.314835442  -0.131731938   0.090753214   0.326724648  -0.504309863
 [16]   0.522419894  -0.458490815  -0.922188177   1.312544072  -0.124784861
 [21]  -0.440201131  -0.376074075   0.484759007  -0.544084907   0.184140601
 [26]   0.634605831  -1.015191304  -0.392407326   0.069140836   0.837570607
 [31]  -0.734046990   0.009650584  -0.297811017  -0.894844413   1.254269251
 [36]  -2.202675529   3.181080668   2.738269460  -1.531934991  -0.441972078
 [41]  -0.111205739   0.347052040   0.812613401   1.056684583  -0.498294836
 [46]  -0.318961547  -0.109851318  -0.118844912   0.404173405  -0.910582285
 [51]  -0.353860467  -0.750922999  -0.703591979  -0.637060347  -0.282754755
 [56]  -0.953784737   1.576556620   4.151024359  -5.425327217  -6.103292196
 [61]   7.943888186 -13.463531790   5.869748465 -14.205872960  -5.045698842
 [66]   6.001954472   4.930371803  -1.892510511   1.850741003  -0.954016972
 [71]  -0.077456198   0.040999835  -0.446823649   0.127273533   0.127966102
 [76]   0.216028033   0.626917525   0.282341328   0.328576480  -0.157644004
 [81]  -0.937382208   1.287429037   0.900623061  -0.677630409   0.427116916
 [86]   0.246673589   0.204713960  -0.177800003   0.290096733   0.758407267
 [91]  -0.328556185  -0.330455346  -0.526235619  -0.489013356   0.475158246
 [96]   0.430567333  -0.775044149   0.139062847   0.374927797  -0.528934679
[101]   0.217091044  -0.019686328   0.690038054  -0.450631659   0.530362959
[106]  -0.466588401   0.895308589   0.013337137  -0.257514294  -0.346425256
[111]   0.002790152   0.565433354  -1.038591166   1.439547986  -0.475994171
[116]  -0.573993908   0.844415185  -0.778530803  -0.743884821   1.258147231
[121]  -0.088087152   0.508910627  -0.071854449   0.410070978   0.471372207
[126]   0.094210278   1.334666193  -0.010790060  -0.305813138  -0.347626733
[131]  -0.467378439   0.372987762   0.481824018   0.415398181  -0.180618112
[136]   1.013615048  -0.156073342   0.356076568   0.169108466   0.275734683
[141]  -0.648042994   0.269037495   0.669168433  -0.239254253   0.796882449
[146]   1.336804388  -0.354919126  -0.525481668  -0.066679296  -0.645930518
[151]   0.415104329   1.070218821   2.305348685  -3.405189139  -3.799563891
[156]   0.721310801  -0.864861449  -1.169885359   0.052965774  -0.681096223
[161]  -0.227592654   0.538791441   0.123075072   0.471443863  -0.598493272
[166]  -0.575874729  -0.497991275  -1.149177081  -0.391882551  -0.724743988
[171]   0.151001413  -0.596898412   0.762378302  -1.740324011   0.255643898
[176]   0.417552215  -0.641130460  -0.775619616   0.968210920  -0.110971587
[181]  -0.143987039  -0.041898461   0.384757277   0.303919564   0.367943147
[186]  -0.123326308   0.506591242   0.631918157  -0.265859230   0.325193212
[191]   0.532946942   0.633710920   0.590115624   0.307122036   0.391484459
[196]  -0.036289366  -0.614109628  -0.638930907   0.881656376  -1.584292446




Call:
garch(x = data2, order = c(0, 1))

Model:
GARCH(0,1)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.57713 -0.68644  0.01396  0.79931  2.85119 

Coefficient(s):
    Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
a0   0.21135     0.04085    5.174 2.30e-07 ***
a1   0.87577     0.16163    5.418 6.02e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Diagnostic Tests:
    Jarque Bera Test

data:  Residuals
X-squared = 1.4612, df = 2, p-value = 0.4816


    Box-Ljung test

data:  Squared.Residuals
X-squared = 0.0027, df = 1, p-value = 0.9584


Call:
garch(x = data2, order = c(1, 1))

Model:
GARCH(1,1)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-2.257745 -0.252623  0.006404  0.248729  1.680547 

Coefficient(s):
    Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
a0 3.497e+00   8.228e-01    4.251 2.13e-05 ***
a1 1.048e+00   8.054e-01    1.301    0.193    
b1 2.371e-14   1.779e-01    0.000    1.000    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Diagnostic Tests:
    Jarque Bera Test

data:  Residuals
X-squared = 143.2293, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16


    Box-Ljung test

data:  Squared.Residuals
X-squared = 15.6938, df = 1, p-value = 7.447e-05

Call:
garch(x = data2, order = c(1, 2))

Model:
GARCH(1,2)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-3.301812 -0.268550  0.006167  0.257807  2.279465 

Coefficient(s):
    Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)  
a0 3.327e+00   2.675e+00    1.244    0.214  
a1 1.341e-01   7.183e-02    1.866    0.062 .
a2 1.299e-01   1.559e-01    0.833    0.405  
b1 1.113e-13   7.818e-01    0.000    1.000  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Diagnostic Tests:
    Jarque Bera Test

data:  Residuals
X-squared = 470.4355, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16


    Box-Ljung test

data:  Squared.Residuals
X-squared = 60.2426, df = 1, p-value = 8.438e-15
```

Comment: Can you post your data?

Comment: The data looks like it *might* be consistent with GARCH. You could fit a GARCH model and then look to see if there's substantive structure left in standardized residuals.

Comment: I posted my data . Here is the result of garch(0,1). Can you help me interpret the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of testing for (G)ARCH effects in time series, and using your data, I am reporting two of the most commonly used two-sided tests:

1. [Engle's LM test](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0165-1765%2891%2990221-6) (implemented in `ArchTest()` from the `FinTS` package)
2. [McLeod-Li test](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9892.1983.tb00373.x) (implemented in `McLeod.Li.test()` from the TSA package)

In both cases, using your data, the null of no ARCH effects is strongly rejected when checking up to lag 12.

```
library(FinTS)
library(TSA)

dfGARCH = read.table(textConnection('[1]   0.187415738   0.477868164   0.295777631   0.575167970   0.469157108
  [6]   0.328171826   1.292894322  -0.847711535   0.392077876   0.116540719
 [11]   0.314835442  -0.131731938   0.090753214   0.326724648  -0.504309863
                          [16]   0.522419894  -0.458490815  -0.922188177   1.312544072  -0.124784861
                          [21]  -0.440201131  -0.376074075   0.484759007  -0.544084907   0.184140601
                          [26]   0.634605831  -1.015191304  -0.392407326   0.069140836   0.837570607
                          [31]  -0.734046990   0.009650584  -0.297811017  -0.894844413   1.254269251
                          [36]  -2.202675529   3.181080668   2.738269460  -1.531934991  -0.441972078
                          [41]  -0.111205739   0.347052040   0.812613401   1.056684583  -0.498294836
                          [46]  -0.318961547  -0.109851318  -0.118844912   0.404173405  -0.910582285
                          [51]  -0.353860467  -0.750922999  -0.703591979  -0.637060347  -0.282754755
                          [56]  -0.953784737   1.576556620   4.151024359  -5.425327217  -6.103292196
                          [61]   7.943888186 -13.463531790   5.869748465 -14.205872960  -5.045698842
                          [66]   6.001954472   4.930371803  -1.892510511   1.850741003  -0.954016972
                          [71]  -0.077456198   0.040999835  -0.446823649   0.127273533   0.127966102
                          [76]   0.216028033   0.626917525   0.282341328   0.328576480  -0.157644004
                          [81]  -0.937382208   1.287429037   0.900623061  -0.677630409   0.427116916
                          [86]   0.246673589   0.204713960  -0.177800003   0.290096733   0.758407267
                          [91]  -0.328556185  -0.330455346  -0.526235619  -0.489013356   0.475158246
                          [96]   0.430567333  -0.775044149   0.139062847   0.374927797  -0.528934679
                          [101]   0.217091044  -0.019686328   0.690038054  -0.450631659   0.530362959
                          [106]  -0.466588401   0.895308589   0.013337137  -0.257514294  -0.346425256
                          [111]   0.002790152   0.565433354  -1.038591166   1.439547986  -0.475994171
                          [116]  -0.573993908   0.844415185  -0.778530803  -0.743884821   1.258147231
                          [121]  -0.088087152   0.508910627  -0.071854449   0.410070978   0.471372207
                          [126]   0.094210278   1.334666193  -0.010790060  -0.305813138  -0.347626733
                          [131]  -0.467378439   0.372987762   0.481824018   0.415398181  -0.180618112
                          [136]   1.013615048  -0.156073342   0.356076568   0.169108466   0.275734683
                          [141]  -0.648042994   0.269037495   0.669168433  -0.239254253   0.796882449
                          [146]   1.336804388  -0.354919126  -0.525481668  -0.066679296  -0.645930518
                          [151]   0.415104329   1.070218821   2.305348685  -3.405189139  -3.799563891
                          [156]   0.721310801  -0.864861449  -1.169885359   0.052965774  -0.681096223
                          [161]  -0.227592654   0.538791441   0.123075072   0.471443863  -0.598493272
                          [166]  -0.575874729  -0.497991275  -1.149177081  -0.391882551  -0.724743988
                          [171]   0.151001413  -0.596898412   0.762378302  -1.740324011   0.255643898
                          [176]   0.417552215  -0.641130460  -0.775619616   0.968210920  -0.110971587
                          [181]  -0.143987039  -0.041898461   0.384757277   0.303919564   0.367943147
                          [186]  -0.123326308   0.506591242   0.631918157  -0.265859230   0.325193212
                          [191]   0.532946942   0.633710920   0.590115624   0.307122036   0.391484459
                          [196]  -0.036289366  -0.614109628  -0.638930907   0.881656376  -1.584292446'))

dfGARCH$V1 = NULL
tsGARCH = as.ts(c(t(as.matrix(dfGARCH))))

#==========================================================
# Engle's LM test for ARCH effects
#==========================================================
ArchTest(tsGARCH, lags = 12, demean = FALSE)

#==========================================================
# McLeod-Li test for ARCH effects
#==========================================================
McLeod.Li.test(y = tsGARCH, gof.lag = 12, plot = FALSE)$p.values
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you think about GARCH(0,1), GARCH(1,1) AND GARCH(1,2) results I put abve?